# RSpec stub object that doesn't exist yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm needing to stub an ActiveRecord model before it has been retrieved from the db. Here's a simplified example:

model.rb:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.first_bar
    find(id: 1).bar
  end

  def bar
    'not the value I want'
  end
end
```

model_spec.rb:

```
let(:model) { Model.create } # => <Model id:1>
before { allow(model).to receive(:bar).and_return('the value I need stubbed') }

it { expect(Model.some_value).to eq('the value I need stubbed') }
```

Obviously, this test fails because the object that is retrieved in `Model.first_bar` is a different object than the one that was stubbed.

Caveats:

- I can't use `allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:first_bar)` because I'm using other instances of that model elsewhere in the real test.
- I can't use `allow(Model).to receive(:first).with(id: 1)` because for my use case, it's too brittle.

Ideally, I need something like `allow_any_instance_of(Model).with_attributes(id: 1)`, so any object with those particular values gets stubbed.

Comment: This seems like an X and Y problem, can you instead tell use the actual behaviour you are trying to test instead of getting lost in the specifics of how to test it?

Comment: Why not stub `first_bar`?

Answer (score -1):

> I can't use `allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:first_bar)`
>   because I'm using other instances of that model elsewhere in the real
>   test.

This doesn't make sense. `first_bar` is a class method, so instances would not call it. Are you familiar with the difference between class and instance methods?

I think `allow(Model).to receive(:first_bar)` will give you the functionality that you are looking for.

Alternately, you could do

```
allow_(Model).to receive(:find).with(id:1).and_return ...
```